# form returned from AJAX request is not recognized as 'remote' when submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

In my rails3 application, a user can add an item to a list by clicking an "add item" link.  Clicking this link makes AJAX call to grab the new_item form.  That part I have working.  The problem is that when I submit the new_item form, it doesn't seem to be recognized as a "remote" form even though I've specified :remote => true.  It's clear that I need to re-initialize the UJS or something after the new_item form is returned from the server and injected into the page, but I don't know how?

Here's my code:

**_new.html.haml (new item form)**

```
= form_for [@list, @item], :remote => true, :html => {:class => 'form-inline'} do |f|
  .input-append
    = f.text_field "name", :class => 'input-large', :placeholder => "Add item to this list"
    %button#picture.btn
      %span.icon-camera
    %button#link.btn{:style => "font-size: 10px;"} 
      http://
  #link-field.field.margin.hidden-field-margin
    = f.text_field "link", :placeholder => "http://www.link.com", :style => "width: 325px"
  #picture-field.field.margin.hidden-field-margin
    = f.file_field "picture"
    = f.hidden_field "picture_cache"
  .clearfix
  = f.submit "Add Item", :class => 'btn', :id => "add-item"
```

**lists.js.coffee**

```
# this retrieves the new item form and places it in-line in the page        
$("#new_list")
    .bind "ajax:success", (evt, xhr, settings) -> 
        $("#list-item").html(xhr)

# when the new item form (returned from the server) is submitted here, it doesn't appear to be submitted via AJAX
$("#new_item #add-item")
    .live "ajax:success", (evt, xhr, settings) ->
        alert "this request worked"
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  def create
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
    @item = @list.items.create!(params[:item])
    if @item.save
      respond_with do |f|
        f.html do
          if request.xhr?
            f.json { render :json => {:result => "ok"}}
          else
            redirect_to @list, :notice => "Item was successfully created."
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I submit the new_item form I get an error in the JS console which looks like this... I have a create.js.erb template which is just blank, but it's not looking for this and clearly not recognizing the request as an ajax request.  How do i get the form returned from the server to be 'ujs' enabled again for lack of a better word?

```
Template is missing

Missing template items/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in: * "/Users/aressidi/Projects/intralist/app/views" * "/Users/aressidi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
```

**Edit - here's the updated controller code that allows the alert to be triggered.**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  def create
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
    @item = @list.items.create!(params[:item])
    if @item.save
      respond_with do |f|
        f.html do
          if request.xhr?
            render :json => {:result => "ok"}
          else
            redirect_to @list
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why don't you try `respond_to :js` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain `:remote => true` makes a request that accepts `application/javascript, */*` (or something similar). But your controller does not respond to javascript, so it tries to render html template.

Try to force `json` in the form:

```
= form_for [@list, @item], :remote => true, :html => {:class => 'form-inline', 'data-type' => 'json'} do |f|
```

Comment: Thanks Dimuch, i wasn't sure what was happening there and understanding that the controller was trying to render HTML helped me hone in on the solution.  I've posted an update above.  Just required some changes to the controller code to at least get the alert working.