# render partial from controller with :layout => !request.xhr? returns missing template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I cloned and tweak this [rails app](https://github.com/chadokruse/rails-prelaunch-signup-1click) and I am experiencing some trouble with rendering a partial when on ajax request, in the logs I see that the guilty line is in the registrations_controller.rb (Devise)

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        (render(:partial => 'thankyou', :layout => false) && return)  if request.xhr?
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        resource.update_attribute(:encrypted_password, nil) # make sure there is no password
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        (render(:partial => 'thankyou', :layout => false) && return)  if request.xhr?
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      render :partial => 'email_capture', :action => :new, :layout => !request.xhr?**
    end
  end

  protected

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/thankyou.html'
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

The error message returned is this:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing partial
>
> with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder,
>   :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:   *
>   "/Users/Davide/Documents/Jobsite/rails-prelaunch-signup-1click/app/views"
>   * "/Users/Davide/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise_invitable-1.1.8/app/views"
>   * "/Users/Davide/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.4/app/views"

Interestingly if I remove the :layout => !=request.xhr? parameter the partial gets found but the page refreshes and the loses all the stylesheets and other assets.

Any idea where should I start looking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have also cloned and modified that project, and ran into nearly the same issue.  For me, the problem would appear after the second failure of saving a bad email address--but the result was identical.

By using context and information from the following question/answer:
[form returned from AJAX request is not recognized as 'remote' when submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205346/form-returned-from-ajax-request-is-not-recognized-as-remote-when-submitted)

I was able to make a change that resolved my issue.  In _email_capture.html.erb, add `:remote => true,`  to the simple_form_for line.  In my case, the whole revised line is:

```
<%= simple_form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :remote => true, :url => registration_path(resource_name) , :html => {:class => 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
```

Hope this helps you, too!